# how can I drop a specific sessionid in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, sessionid

Is it possible to drop or to expire right away an especific session id via code on a web aplication? I'm using VB.net

What i'm trying to do is to give an user the power to drop the session variable of another user.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to expand on the answer that Xander gave:

You can keep a list of expired sessions (either in a datatable or a dictionary). When the session makes another request, check to see if the session is dropped and if so, call the code that Xander gave:

```
Session.Abandon
```

TO store sessionIDs without a database (though non-permanent storage isn't a good idea) in a class you can say

```
Public Shared Sessions as new List(of string)
```

And when pages load, you can check whether the sessionID is in the list using

```
Sessions.contains(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID)
```

**Note**

Making the variable shared makes the session list accessible from all threads. Otherwise it will only be available to the instance that is being modified.

I would also like to know how you plan on getting the session ID, but based on the question, I would assume you have a plan for that